# Weird NSString leak

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

This code gives me a leak - over 100 mb by 100 iterations. If i write [imageName release] it crashes with "message sent to deallocated instance". I just can't even think what can be the source of a problem.

```
NSString* imageName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
imageName =[imageName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"];
imageName =[imageName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@"-"];

[ret setQuestionImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"jpg"]]];
```

Comment: Where is `ret` from? Do you have new one for each iteration? Do they all stick around? If you retain 100 JPEG images, that could be 100 MB easily.

Comment: ret is created dynamically for each iteration and i release it every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the strings and images created by these convenience methods are autoreleased, and the autoreleasing doesn't occur early enough. If you eplicitly release them, however, they'll be double-freed upon autorelease. Try to wrap all iterations into an autorelease pool:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString *imageName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
imageName = [imageName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"];
imageName = [imageName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@"-"];

[ret setQuestionImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"jpg"]]];
[pool release];
```

Comment: Also, if you improved your overall coding/indentation style a bit, that would help making the code more readable. :)

Comment: thanks! Well, the problem was in bad dealloc for "ret" object :)